# Adding Specific Number from a Matrix within a List

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, matrix

I have a list initialized:

```
best_selected = [[2, 3, 0, 1], [1, 3, 0, 2], [1, 2, 3, 0], [1, 0, 2, 3]]
                      0              1             2             3

finalList = [[0, 1308, 17410, 16098], [1246, 0, 17557, 16244], [17675, 18002, 0, 5618], [16257, 16584, 5508, 0]]
                        0                         1                        2                   3
```

The finalList as a matrix looks like this:

```
    [[    0  1308 17410 16098]
     [ 1246     0 17557 16244]
     [17675 18002     0  5618]
     [16257 16584  5508     0]]
```

What I'm trying to do is to iterate in every list of best_selected and add them depending on which index it is in on the other list. And lets say in the first iteration is [2, 3, 0, 1] in best_selected list. The first element in the list is 2 so I'm going to start in :

```
    [[    0  1308 17410 16098]
     [ 1246     0 17557 16244]
 --> [17675 18002     0  5618]
     [16257 16584  5508     0]]
```

Since the next number of 2 is 3 respectively in the first iteration of the best_selected, so I would get 5618 as the first value to be in the index. Since it stopped at 3 I would now check next at:

```
    [[    0  1308 17410 16098]
     [ 1246     0 17557 16244]
     [17675 18002     0  5618]
 --> [16257 16584  5508     0]]
```

As the next element of 3 is 0*, then I would try to add 16257 in the variable 'index' that contained the value 5618 so the index would now contain the value of 16257 + 5618. I'm trying to do that in each of every iteration of best_selected and so far I'm having errors

The code I'm trying to work out:

```
count = len(best_selected)
index = 0
j = 0 
val = best_selected[0]
while count != 0:
    index = index + finalList[best_selected[val]]
    if counter == 1:
        pass
    else:
        val = best_selected[j+1]
    j = j + 1
    counter = counter - 1
print(index)
```

Any fix or an easy solution would highly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a sliding window of the current item and the next item in the sublist. You could just iterate over the sublists and then over the range `range(len(sublist)-1)`, so that you can assign the first index to `i = sublist[indx]` and the second to `j = sublist[indx+1]`.

```
index = 0

for sublist in best_selected:
    for indx in range(len(sublist)-1):
        i = sublist[indx]
        j = sublist[indx+1]
        index += finalList[i][j]
```

The nicer variant would be to `zip` the sublist with `sublist[1:]` to get tuples with the indices which you can immediately unpack in the head of the loop:

```
for sublist in best_selected:
    for i, j in zip(sublist, sublist[1:]):
        index += finalList[i][j]
```

---

Here's the solution with the separate sublist sums:

```
sums = []

for sublist in best_selected:
    sublist_sum = 0
    for i, j in zip(sublist, sublist[1:]):
        sublist_sum += finalList[i][j]
    sums.append(sublist_sum)

print(sums)
print(sum(sums))
```

Comment: How to do I stop it or append the values(index in this case) during each sub-list?  Like for example [2, 3, 0, 1], then I'll append the total for that, next is [1, 3, 0, 2], and so on. Like it  doesn't accumulate until the end of the list

Comment: You want the sums of each sublist, right? Then add a new `sum_ = 0` variable between the two loops and add the items of the `finalList` to this variable and after each iteration of the inner loop, append this `sum_` to another list. At the end of the program, you can just call `sum(another_list)` to get the total.